# ImportXML function in Google Sheets produces error 'Imported content is empty'!

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Here is the ImportXML formula I am using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RY.TO/profile",K6)
```

Cell K6 contains the following xpath query:

```
//*[@id="Col1-0-Profile-Proxy"]/section/div[1]/div/div/p[2]/strong[1]
```

I got the xpath query by using the Copy XPath function in Google Chrome (e.g. after inspecting the element I am interested in).

The element I am interested in is the Sector associated with the Royal Bank (e.g. Financial Services)

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!!

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Feel free to [upvote/accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Using the Copy XPath function is a handy feature. However, the suggested query is usually clumsy and sometimes does not yield the desired result. Here is an alternative approach:

```
//span[.='Sector']/following-sibling::strong[1]
```

Select the `span` that has the innerHtml "Sector" and then select the following `strong` sibling; finally, we can select the `/text()` directly too like this:

```
=IMPORTXML($A$10;"//span[.='Sector']/following-sibling::strong[1]/text()")
```

which returns: `Financial Services`